# How can I skip the zeros in a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix with columns filled with zeros and I want to copy the matrix into a new matrix but to skip the columns with the zeros.

Is there any command that can help me? I tried to do it with the sparse command but I didn't really understand what happens there. It skips the zeros but when you want to know how many columns you have in the new matrix it still shows the initial size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite simple

```
>> noZeros = withZeros(:, any( withZeros, 1 ) )
```

The command `any( withZeros, 1 )` returns a logical vector of length `size(A,2)` with `true` for each column in `withZeros` that has at least one non-zero entry.

Alternatively, you can drop the columns

```
>> withZeros(:, all( withZeros == 0, 1 ) ) = [];
```

Look at the documentation of [`any`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) and [`all`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) for more information.

Comment: Since most MATLAB built-in functions operate on columns, I don't really see the point in specifying the first dimension explicitly. Yes, I know, you're probably going to say that you do it for clarity :) but to me it just clutters the code (same goes for writing `withZeros == 0` instead of `~withZeros`).

Comment: @EitanT as a person that jumps back and forth from Matlab to python to C++ where each environment has its own modus-operandi I find it quite useful to be over-specific. But I can easily see your point as well. Shana Tova.

Comment: Heh :) It's a matter of style after all, so it's subjective. Can't argue with that. Thanks, and גמר חתימה טובה to you too :)

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you have a random matrix with a size of 100x100

```
A = rand(100);
```

and let's assume the 15th column is zero

```
A(:,15) = 0;
```

Then you can delete this column with

```
A=A(:,any(A))
```

Comment: Which is basically what @Shai answered =)

Comment: I know Robert, I was typing my answer and when I pressed submit, his answer was already there (Need to become faster). :)

Comment: You deserve +1 just for the bulling x)